# How I can open a ModalDialog about a LinkButton from a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, listview, modal-dialog

I want open a Dialog with Controls and it must open if I click on a LinkButton in a ListView. I want make it with a CommandName and OnCommand Argumen.

My Application:

In My Application can a User search other Users about a textBox and list the users in a ListView. Than he can display more Informations about one User if the user click on the LinkButton.

[image]

If I make it about a normal Button, the Dialog open but if I make it about the LinkButton with CommandName it Don't work.

My Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidForModel" runat="server" />

    <asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
       </asp:scriptmanager> 

       <asp:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" 
                runat="server" cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" 
                okcontrolid="btnOkay" targetcontrolid="hidForModel" 
                popupcontrolid="Panel1" popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" 
                drag="true" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">

</asp:modalpopupextender>

            <div class="popupConfirmation" id="Panel1" >
              <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PopupHeader" CssClass="modalPopup">Benutzerinformationen</asp:Panel>
                <div class="Body">
                    Hallo
                    <asp:Button id="btnOkay" runat="server" text="Speichern" />
                    <asp:Button id="btnCancel" runat="server" text="Abbrechen" />
                </div>

            </div>


    <div class="header">
        <table id="SuchTabelle" runat="server" border="0">

            <tr>
                <th><asp:Label ID="id_SearchUser" runat="server" Text="lblSearchUser"></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:TextBox ID="txtBenutzer" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><asp:Label ID="id_location" runat="server" Text="lblLocation"></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:DropDownList ID="dropWerk" runat="server" Width="250px" /></th>
                <th><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Suchen" 
                                onclick="btnBenutzerSuchen_Click" Width="219px" /></th>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <div id="bild">
            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/lw_logo.jpg" Height="58px" 
                Width="277px" />
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="bodyList">



        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="UserTable" runat="server" border="0" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr style="background-color:#E5E5FE" class="TableClass">
                    <th id="th1" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBenutzer" runat="server" >id_Benutzer</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th2" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkemail" runat="server" >id_Email</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th3" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkVorname" runat="server" >id_Vorname</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th4" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNachname" runat="server" >id_Nachname</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th5" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTelefon" runat="server" >id_Telefon</asp:LinkButton></th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr class="TableClass">    
                <td align="left" ><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server"  /></td>

              <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <AlternatingItemTemplate>

            <tr class="TableClass"> 

                <td align="left" ><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server" /></td>

                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

            </tr>

        </AlternatingItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>

        <br />
        <br />

    </div>

    </form>
```

My C# Code:

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                ModalPopupExtender1.Show(); // error :(

            }

        }
```

My Errortext:

System.InvalidOperationException: The ListView "myListView" has one SelectedIndexChanging-Event execute, which was not treated.

I need help :(

The Update:

```
protected void myListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                txtVorname.Text = "test";

                PopUpDialog.Show();  //<-- Here is the error 

            }
        }
```

I make a breakpoint and see ...

[image]

tarasov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Handle "ItemCommand" Event of "ListView":**

```
protected void myListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "Select"))
    {
      ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
      //your code
    }
 }
```

Comment: No overload for 'myListView_ItemCommand "agrees match with the delegates' System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventHandler" ---Zeile 99:                 <td align="left" ><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="myListView_ItemCommand" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server"  /></td>

Comment: You have to add event on ListView (not on LinkButton)          <asp:ListView runat="server" 
        ID="myListView"
        OnItemCommand="myListView_ItemCommand">...... </asp:ListView>

Comment: oh ok but if I click on the LinkButton I get the error...System.InvalidOperationException: The ListView "myListView" has one SelectedIndexChanging-Event execute, which was not treated.
:(